# Update manager not worknig and Red icon on my menu panel

Tags: package-management, icons, update-manager, dependencies, 14.04

I've been upgrading my ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 LTS,during the installation process, I accidentally lost power after this i try to turnon my machine, it shows red icon with Error message

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

when i click this it shows an error message:

```
An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click from the right click window or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message was:
'Error:BrokenCount >0'.
This usually means that your installed installed packages have unmet dependencies
```

Experts says to run this command:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I got the following error

```
dpkg: error processing package libreadline6:i386 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libreadline6:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And also update manager not working

here is  the screenshot:

[image]

I have been looking around but am unable to find a way to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

The package should still be in the package cache, so try

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives
sudo dpkg -i libreadline6_6.2-9ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

Alternatively you can download the package from http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/libreadline6

Comment: hey photon i got this error:                                   dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process     what should i do now?

Comment: The lock file from the interrupted installation is still present, remove it with `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock`

Comment: @ Photon this is what am getting:                               dpkg: error processing archive libreadline6_6.2-9ubuntu1_i386.deb (--install):
cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
libreadline6_6.2-9ubuntu1_i386.deb

Comment: Then just download it from the URL I posted above (and be sure to be in the right directory when executing dpkg).

Comment: Yeah right, let you know once i done

Comment: @ Photon , i have installed libreadline6 by using following command sudo apt-get install libreadline6 libreadline6-devafter this i try to fix broken packages by using sudo apt-get -f  i got the same error message which was mention in the question.